# Proof for f must be a constant polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, proof-explanation

Suppose $f$ is a complex polynomial in $z$ and $\bar z$. Assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$.

How do you prove that $f$ here **MUST** be a constant polynomial?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Well, I understand the theory but I just dont understand how to prove that...